# How to transforming a function from from spherical to Cartesian coordinates system using Matlalb code

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems

The function sph2cart is used to transform spherical coordinates into Cartesian. But how to transform a function of polar coordinate into a function of Cartesian coordinates using Matlab code. For example how to transform the spherical harmonic Y(r,θ,φ) into Cartesian coordinates Y(x,y,z).

Comment: How is your function defined? Is it an `m`-file, and anonymous function, an array of values?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I would recommend writing your own function for these type of transformations. `phir2xy=@(phi,r)r.*[cos(phi) sin(phi)];` is a simple 2D example, but you can do something similar for your 3D transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a symbolic function or anonymous function; what stops you from replacing r, θ and φ by their [transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#To_Spherical_coordinates) using [`subs`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)? Followingly, you can use [`simplify`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html).